# Implementing user-entered integer in for loop C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, variables

The issue: I have a lab that asks us to write a  console app that ask the user to enter an integer. Your program should then use a for loop to output the numbers from 0 up to the value entered by the user.

I think I need to convert a user entered value (I'm thinking string) to an integer first, like this

```
        string val;
        int ival;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer value: ");
        val = Console.ReadLine();
        ival = Convert.ToInt32(val);
```

Then, I have to initiate the for loop, which I think would look like this, but I'm not certain. I do not understand how to use the user-entered value into the for loop. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

```
for (int i = //user entered variable//; i == 0; i--)
{ 
Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

The full source code I'm trying to run in visual studio

```
        string val;
        int ival;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter an integer value: ");
        val = Console.ReadLine();
        ival = Convert.ToInt32(val);

        for (int i = 0; i >= ival; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
```

Comment: Going "from 0 up to the value" would be `for(int i = 0; i <= ival; ++i)` (assuming it's inclusive). Really, you can use that variable like you would use any variable, it's not special.

Answer (score 0):

well how about

```
for (int i = 0;i <= ival; i++)
{ 
   Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

also note, you are going to have to deal with the case where a user enters an invalid string. Use `Int32.TryParse`

Comment: Hey there, thank you for the reply. I'm very new to this still, so this may seem silly, but where would I type in Int32.TryParse? and, when I try to put it all together in Visual Basic, it compiles, but only displays the value I entered, it doesn't actually execute the loop. do you have any insight on why that may be? Thank you again for the time.

Comment: @ultex113 please type into the question the full source code of what you are running. Note = this is not visual basic it is c#

Comment: I put the code in the original post at the bottom, thank you.

Comment: @ultex113 but you typed my answer in wrong, read it again

Comment: @ultex113 try typing in 'hello' instead of a number and see what happens